# Clear collected in GA data

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to clear collected in GA data?

I tried to move the view into trash bin, but the data is still persisted. What else may I try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to remove data completely and immediately. It will be available in Trash bin and can be restored during about 30 days.